# import error when trying to use pip command in ubuntu terminal

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, terminal, pip

I just installed pip with ubuntu onto my laptop. Whenever I try to use pip in the terminal, I keep getting this error:

```
lopuj@lopuj-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~$ pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.4.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-1.1.5-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
    def get_entry_info(dist, group, name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-1.1.5-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2394, in load_entry_point
    break
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-1.1.5-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2108, in load
    name = some.module:some.attr [extra1,extra2]
ImportError: No module named 'pip'
lopuj@lopuj-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~$ ^C
lopuj@lopuj-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~$
```

How can I stop this from happening so i can just type in commands like 'pip install Django==1.7.1'?

Answer (score 0):

Your referencing

```
usr/local
```

but pip is installed at

```
usr/lib
```

Check your installation. I would reinstall using esay_install and then open/close terminal.

Comment: lopuj@lopuj-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~$ sudo easy_install pip
    [sudo] password for lopuj: 
    Searching for pip
    Best match: pip 1.4.1
    Processing pip-1.4.1-py3.4.egg
    pip 1.4.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
    Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
    Installing pip-3.4 script to /usr/local/bin

    Using /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-1.4.1-py3.4.egg
    Processing dependencies for pip
    Finished processing dependencies for pip
    lopuj@lopuj-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~$

Comment: I tried reinstalling it. Is there any way I can get it to intall to usr/lib instead of usr/local. I'm not sure why it keeps going there?

Comment: $ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.4
Afterwards you can install the latest setuptools for the appropriate python, e.g

$ python{2.7,3.4} -m pip install -U setuptools